# Range of a function without graphing

Tags: functions, notation

I have the following function:

$ f(x) = (x^2 − 4)^3 + 1 $

And I've applied the following steps to get the range of the function:

$ g: x \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow x^2+4 \in [-4,+\infty[$

$ h: x \in [-4,+\infty[ \rightarrow x^3 \in [-64,+\infty[ $

$ f(X) = [-63,+\infty[ $

Is this procedure formally valid? Is there something that should be improved?

Comment: Well why do you have $x^2-4$ in $f(x)$ but $x^2+4$ in $g$?

Comment: the steps are valid, just as Alex mentioned there is $+-$ mistake in $g$. Just, if you describe a function element-wise you would use $\mapsto$ : $g: \mathbb{R}\ni x \mapsto x^2-4 \in [-4,\infty[$